# Breadcrumbs in Blogger

Tags: xml, blogger, breadcrumbs

The Breadcrumbs in my blog are not well configured and I can not solve the problem.

On both the home page where show the posts and inside them, display the first bookmark, I would like to show all the bookmarks on the main page and within the posts show the full path.

I found in my template the Breadcrumbs configuration which is as follows:

```
        <b:includable id='postCategory' var='post'>
          <!-- Post Label/Category -->
          <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
            <span class='post-tag'>
              <data:post.labels.first.name/>
            </span>
          </b:if>
        </b:includable>
```

I tried everything and I researched a lot, but since my knowledge is not many and I did not find anything on the internet, I decided to ask for help.

Does anyone know what modifications I have to make to make it look the way I want it?

My Blog: https://xamasurbanossioux.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please, explain your problem more clearly!

Comment: @Bassam , I'm Brazilian and my English is not very good, but I'll try to explain it again, I want to show the full path in Breadcrumb on my blog. Access, you will understand. My Blog: xamasurbanossioux.blogspot.com

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not proper here to add [SOLVED] to the title. If an answer below has solved your problem, mark it as accepted and everyone knows it's been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show a full clickable Breadcrumbs, you need to modify your code to the following:

```
<b:includable id='postCategory' var='post'>
  <!-- Post Label/Category -->
  <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <span class='post-tag'>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
        <a expr:href="data:blog.homepageUrl"><data:messages.home/></a> &gt;&gt;
      </b:if>
      <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
        <a expr:href="data:label.url"><data:label.name/></a>
        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != "true"'>&gt;&gt;</b:if>
      </b:loop>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>
        &gt;&gt;<span><data:post.title/></span> 
      </b:if>
    </span>
  </b:if>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: this code makes the full path appear, but only with the first tag, the others do not.

Comment: Also I think no need for post title, it's too long

Comment: My idea is to show on the homepage just the tags and within the article the full path,

it's possible?

Comment: almost perfect, but can I add some symbol between tags?

Comment: Symbol like what?

Comment: I like this model:

You are here: Home Page >> Tag1 >> Tag2 >> Tag3 >> Post title ...

Can you give me this last help?

Comment: Glad it helped please, consider accepting my answer. have a nice day